# How to export the data from table to csv file by applying sort on one column

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have 2 billion of records in table in SQL developer and wanted to export the records in csv file but while exporting data I want to sort one column in ascending order. Is there any efficient or quick way to do this?
for ex:
Suppose the table name is TEMP and i want to sort the A_KEY column in ascending order and then export it

```
/* TEMP 
 P_ID   ADDRESS       A_KEY
    1   242 Street     4       
    2   242 Street     5       
    3   242 Street     3       
    4   242 Long St    1
```

Expected Result in csv file:

P_ID, ADDRESS, A_KEY
4, 242 Long St,1
3, 242 Street,3
1, 242 Street, 4
2, 242 Long St,5

I have tried using below query :

insert into temp2select * from TEMP order by A_KEY ASC;

and then export the table from sqldeveloper but is there any efficient or quick way to direct export records without query?

Answer (score 0):

Losing time on creating a new table (`TEMP2`) won't help because you *are* using `ORDER B`Y clause during `INSERT`, but that means nothing. It is `ORDER BY` in `SELECT` statement that matters.

Therefore, run

```
select * from temp order by a_key;
```

and export result returned by that query.

---

2 billion rows? It'll take time. What will you do with such a CSV file? That's difficult to work with.

If you're trying to *move* data into another Oracle database, then consider using **Data Pump** export and import utilities which are designed for such a purpose.

Comment: I am not trying to move data into another oracle database. I want to use that csv file in java code and perform few operations on that file .But as you said it will take time for 2 billion records so Is there any fastest way to export or generate csv file for millions /billions of records?

Comment: In that case, I'd rather *perform few operations* while data is **in the database**.

Comment: But perform operation while data in database is not an faster way, it is taking too much time so to do it in fast way we use java utility /code .I just want to know the fastest way to export data in csv  .